# show only those custom category which have post

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have created custom taxonomy "market_support_category" which has multiple categories. The below code shows all categories, but I want to show categories which have post.

```
<select class="form-control" name="category">
  <?php echo $tax_terms = get_terms('market_support_category', 
   array('hide_empty' => false)); 
   foreach($tax_terms as $term_single)
   {      
      echo '<option value="'.$term_single->slug.'">'.$term_single->name.'</option>';
    }  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: array('hide_empty' => false));  //true?

Comment: @mayersdesign thanks for ur answer.. you save my lot of time

Answer (score 1):

You have accidentally coded:

```
array('hide_empty' => false));
```

...you need:

```
array('hide_empty' => true));
```

:)